# NPOI number format

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I'm using NPOI library to create excel file, I have problem with formatting price.

```
                ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);

                ICellStyle codeCellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
                ICellStyle priceCellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
                ICellStyle availabilityStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();

                excelSheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
                excelSheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 12 * 256);
                excelSheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 15 * 256);

                List<string> columns = new List<string>() { "Code", "Price", "Availability" };
                IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);

                foreach (var columnData in columns.Select((v, i) => new { Column = v, Index = i }).ToList())
                {
                    row.CreateCell(columnData.Index).SetCellValue(columnData.Column);
                }

                codeCellStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("@");
                priceCellStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("#,##0.00");
                availabilityStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("@");

                int rowIndex = 1;

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
                    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(item.Code);
                    row.Cells[0].CellStyle = codeCellStyle;

                    if (item.HasData)
                    {
                        if (item.Price == "ON DEMAND")
                        {
                            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(item.Price);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ICell priceCell = row.CreateCell(1);

                            row.Cells[1].SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
                            row.Cells[1].CellStyle = priceCellStyle;

                            if (percentage != 0)
                                priceCell.SetCellValue(double.Parse(item.Price) + ((double)percentage / (double)100) * double.Parse(item.Price));
                            else
                                priceCell.SetCellValue(double.Parse(item.Price));
                        }
                        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(item.Availability ? "True" : "False");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("");
                        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("");
                    }
                    rowIndex++;
                }
```

When I have item with price "422,26" it produce excel file with price value 42226,00.
It works fine when I have price "380,00", "4730,00", but problem occurs when I have decimal part in string number.

I tried other suggestions from stackoverflow but I have no luck nothing works on my example.

Comment: Hello xyloto, feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted.  This is acceptable on SO and encouraged instead of putting the answer within the question.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling this format solved my problem

**"#,#0.00"**